# Cakephp button won't direct to view, "automagic" function to do this?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, button

I have a view which I want to have 3 buttons; Save, Save & Next, Save & Previous. The save button is the standard submit type button and it works. The other two buttons show up as buttons, but won't do any action. I've written a file called save_move_next.js to call an action, and gave the button an id and put all the appropriate things where they should be, but it doesn't do a thing.

Is there some prebuilt way to do that? Basically, user clicks the button, action in controller takes over, saves information then moves to next item.

Would putting it above the form fix the issue? Or changing it so it looks like:

```
$this->Form->submit('Button text', array(some controller, action);
$this->Form->submit('Button text', array(some controller, action);
$this->Form->submit('Button text', array(some controller, action);
$this->Form->end();
```

Part of view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->button('Save and next drug', array('type'=>'button','id'=>'save_move_next')); ?>
```

JS function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save_move_next").click(function(){
        var drug_id = $(this).val();
        if(drug_id.length > 0)
        {
            window.location = "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'french_translations', 'action' => 'next'), true) ?>/" + drug_id;
        }
    });

});
```

In Head of default.ctp:

```
echo $javascript->link('save_move_next');
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you running?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not possible by using a `submit` type button. By HTML definitions, a submit button submits the form data to the specified `action` attribute of the form, no exceptions! What you describe requires 'regular' buttons (non-submit) with click events bound to them, like gvLearner suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of Saanch's answer. If cakephp 1.3 is being used, you can determine which button was clicked and simply redirect to the view desired. gvLearner pointed me in the right direction but had some issues with the code he provided.

Buttons in view:

```
echo $form->submit('Save', array('name'=>'save');
echo $form->submit('Save & Next', array('name'=>'saveNext');
```

Code to determine the button clicked and redirect:

```
if (isset($this->params['form']['name-you-gave-the-button-in-the-view']) && $this->params['form']['name-you-gave-the-button-in-the-view'] == 'name-you-gave-the-button-in-the-view') {
  // The button was clicked and you can redirect or whatever here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp can't identify the Submit button id as such. What you can do is make the other two button as ajax calls and change the url to different method and write your logic there.

```
    <a href="#" id="saveNextBtn">Save & Next</a>


    jQuery("#saveNextBtn").bind('submit', function(event) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                beforeSend : function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    jQuery("#sending").show();
                },
                data : jQuery("#saveNextBtn").closest("form").serialize(),
                dataType : "html",
                success : function(data) {
                    jQuery("#success").html(data);
                    jQuery("#sending").hide();
                },
                type : "post",
                url : "\/AppName\/ControllerName\/Method"
            });
            return false;
        });
```

**UPDATE**

I gave this solution based on the assumtion you are using CakePHP 2.1. If you are using CakePHP1.3 you can get the button details from form params.

You can use the following code to achieve that.

```
    echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('name'=>'save');
    echo $this->Form->submit('Save & Next', array('name'=>'savenext');

    if (isset($this->params['form']['submit']) && $this->params['form']['submit'] == "Save") {
      // Save button Clicked
    }
```

Comment: Will i need to add additional helpers and/or components? Would this all go into the view or a seperate file like js? Not super familiar with working with ajax.

Comment: Also, is it just going to display a link? If so, I can already do a link which works.

Comment: I just saw your update, is that all going into the view? Still having trouble with this, lol.